# Are questions about returning to your home country on-topic?

Tags: discussion

If I have questions related to ending my time as an expat, should I ask them on Expatriates?

To be clear, these would be issues that are caused by both of the following (not just one of them):

- having been an expat in the past
- not going to be an expat anymore

Would such questions be off-topic because I will be a non-expat, living in my native country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's an issue that only an expat faces or will face, then yes.  And similarly moving home is like being an expat for the second time.

For example, recent-expats may have questions about filing tax return from overseas if they still need to do so, now that they're no longer living in that country.

However, rather than a blanket statement, as there's always likely to be exceptions, basically - once again, follow the guide of - if the problem faced is not unique to an expat, it's possibly off topic.  Of course no harm in asking, it can always be closed if off-topic as the site evolves.  There's also the chat to ask in, if you don't feel it's suitable for the site, although it's not as busy a chat room as some of the other sites...yet.